# Algorithmic or structural limitations of space-filling Latin hypercube sampling

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, matlab, latin-hypercube

I'm new to Latin hypercube sampling, and am trying to understand if the somewhat odd sampling that results from the Matlab function `lhsdesign` is a limitation of the particular algorithm or something deeper within LHS, which I've failed to realize from the literature.  I suppose the fact that the results are **SO** bad is what makes me doubt that this is Matlab's mistake, though I'm almost certain it is.  A toy example:

```
n=3;                %dimensions
p=1e5;              %samples
s=lhsdesign(n,p);   %default algorithm maximizes min distance between samples
figure
plotmatrix(s.')
figure
scatter3(s(1,:),s(2,:),s(3,:),'.')
xlabel('1'),ylabel('2'),zlabel('3')
```

The following figures result (first figure is with 1e4 samples so that individual points are visible):
[image]
[image]

As is quite visible, there are *p* block-gaps along the main diagonal (testing with other *p* confirms this).  I understand that it's easy to make an LHS that isn't space-filling (e.g. the identity matrix), but [Matlab's explanation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lhsdesign.html) of the algorithm,although brief, doesn't suggest this behavior should arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (I) have specified n and p backward, thus the plots are for 3 samples of a 1E5 dimensional space, and the gaps correspond to LHS doing exactly what it's designed to do.  In short, I'm an idiot.